ag-grid-angular rowIndex conflict when using detailCellRendererParams with detail grid
I have implmented ag-grid-angular with master details true. I'm using detailCellRendererParams to prepare details grid in GridOption.
My grid adding dynamic data after click on add row button for master grid and well as for child grid.
Consider i have one master row with two details row for it.
If i add new master row (index 1) and then go to existing master row (index 0) and add new row in detail grid and again jump back to new master row (index 1) to add child row in detail grid , instead of taking index 1 for master row, it taking index 2 in event. (index of last add child row for master row index 0).
When i click on add child for any master row it should take master row index not last added child row index.
